# How to display a form when I drag a div on drop div position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

when I drag div **A** and drop on **Drop** div, when I drop a div the form div `#formnew1` will be opened.

I used the `onclick` function. But I want to display the `#formdiv` div when I drag a div

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div class="d">
        <div class="draggable1" style="background-color: black;color:white" id="first">A
            <div style="display: none;width:196px;" id="formnew1">
                <div class="container">
                    <form style="background-color: white;" id="targetinsert1">
                        <center>
                            <input type="hidden" name="website" id="website" value="website"/>
                            <input  type="text" name="targetname" id="targetname" placeholder="Target Name" style="margin-bottom: 3%;"/>
                            <br />
                            <input  type="text" name="targetcontent" id="targetcontent" placeholder="Target Content"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="targetinsert1"/>
                            <input  type="button" name="cancel" value="CANCEL" id="cancel" onclick="cancel1();"/>
                        </center>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d1">
        <div id="droppable"  style="width: 25%;height:100px;background-color:grey;"></div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

js code -

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable1").draggable({cursor: "crosshair",
    });
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(".draggable").draggable("disable");
    }
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/3ufk0u6u/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just show form div on drag Event.

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery("#formnew1").show();
        $(".draggable").draggable("disable"); 

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

on line 6 the drop event exectue a function, you need to put your code here.

juste add this :

```
$('#formnew1').show()
```

here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/3ufk0u6u/12/